# While redirect running script ouput to file overwrite the previous ouput

Tags: php, shell, unix

I run a php script from console which has multiple echos while processing and I redirect the script output to file.
I want to overwrite the previous echos output after each echo.

command: php script.php > output.json

after the first echo output.json contains
{"property" : "firstValue" }

after the second echo output.json contains
{"property" : "firstValue" }{"property" : "secondValue" }
and is no longer a valid json
I want after the second echo ouput.json to contain
{"property" : "secondValue" }

Comment: Could you echo the valid json at the end of your script.php?

Comment: Are you actually using the written value while the script is still executing?

Comment: post the crucial lines from your `script.php`

Answer (score 1):

When you want each new line of output to overwrite the last one, read 1 line at a time:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf "%s\n" "${line}" > output.json
done <(php script.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

STDOUT doesn't work that way. If you're generating multiple lines within a single script, and you only want the last one, you could maybe pipe the output through tail:

```
php script.php | tail -1 > output.json
```

Or you could handle the file writing yourself, within the script. Something like:

```
...
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.json', $someOutput);
...
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.json', $someNewOutput);
...
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.json', $someEvenNewerOutput);
```

Comment: I can't write it from script because I run the script on another server and redirect the ouput to current server which is not visible by the server with the script .And I don't want only the last message , I want every message but the current one to override the last one because the ouput represents the script progress.

Comment: JSON requires a well-defined format, you can't stream it. You can either have the remote script output a different format which can be interpreted in a streaming manner (like a list of numbers indicating percentage complete) or have the script output the momentary status to a JSON file on the remote server, then continually pull that file to your local server.